# Is there a term for "language community"?

Tags: terminology

Is there a word for a "language community," especially a minority language embedded with in a larger one?

For example, speakers of Catalán, Irish Gaelic, or perhaps immigrant groups that form communities such as Little Italy or Chinatown?

My mind always reaches for "sprachbund," but that's not correct.

Comment: "speech community" is the normal term I think. It would be better than "language community" because it doesn't suggest that the community is marked by speaking a language (rather than a dialect or variety etc.)

Comment: @xxxxxx https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_community

Comment: @curiousdannii - good job, don't forget  to support what you  say with reliable reference.

Comment: @xxxxxx You're in a touchy mood today?

Comment: @curiousdannii - no, I am just fine.

Comment: If you want a word with *Sprach-*, then perhaps *Sprachgemeinschaft* (lit *community*) or *Sprachinsel*.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer After reading the WP page on *Sprachinsel* I would totally accept that answer if it was used in any literature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal term is [**speech community**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_community).

This has the advantage over "language community" in that it can be used for communities for which the common factor isn't that they all speak some language, but also for communities which speak a particular dialect, or even some minor language variation.

The term is used to focus on identifiable communities of people with shared behaviours. In a context where two languages are in contact, many speakers will be L1 speakers of one language and L2 speakers of the other. Categorising people by the languages they know and speak is not likely to be very productive because of the overlaps. Instead distinct speech communities can be identified based on the languages its members speak at home, in school, in the workplace, the languages they hear on TV etc.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider the term ***[enclave](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/enclave)***:

> - any small, distinct area or group enclosed or isolated within a larger one:
>   *a Chinese-speaking enclave in London*.

(Dictionary.com)